# Getting the user picture URL when Gravatar is installed

Tags: 7, uri, media

I'm trying to print a user's picture without the link to the user's profile which is what `theme('user_picture', array('account' =>$user_item))` will render. If I use `image_style_url('thumbnail', $user->picture->uri)` the Gravatar hook will not be called.

So far the only way I have found to do this is:

```
if (function_exists('_gravatar_get_account_user_picture')) {
    $picture = _gravatar_get_account_user_picture($user);
} else {
    $picture = $user->picture->uri;
}
if (file_valid_uri($picture)) {
    $picture = image_style_url('thumbnail', $picture);
}
```

But this isn't very elegant, especially since I am developing a module and I'd rather not have to explicitly call the Gravatar module.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason calling `theme('user_picture')` returns the user picture as a link is because it's hard coded into the `gravatar_preprocess_user_picture()` function (see lines 148 and 156 of the `gravatar.module` file).

This function uses `_gravatar_get_account_user_picture()` itself so your options are:

- Use that function directly as you're doing at the moment
- Hack the `gravatar_preprocess_user_picture()` function to return the `<img>` tag without the link
- Perform some sort of hideous regex on the rendered HTML in your own preprocess function to extract the `<img>` tag

Personally I'd say the first option is the most desirable.

A slightly more 'Drupal' way to do it might be to use [`module_exists()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_exists/7) instead of checking for the existence of the function itself. It returns `TRUE`:

> if the module is both installed and enabled

While that's not ideal it's a tiny bit more elegant, and if you're worried about the length of code you could shorten it a bit:

```
$uri = module_exists('gravatar') ? _gravatar_get_account_user_picture($user) : $user->picture->uri

if (file_valid_uri($uri)) {
  $options = array('style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'uri' => $uri, 'alt' => 'Alt');
  $img_html = theme('image_style', $options);
}
```

The above code generates the HTML for the `<img>` tag directly using [`theme_image_style()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) without having to get the URI directly which I think is what you're after.

Comment: I'm still really surprised that there's no other way to do this; I mean Drupal does it somewhere internally. I'm pretty reluctant on this because I'm afraid of another module coming along and complicating the issue further, for example if a facebook avatar module were to be used. I really don't like having to program for every exception possible and update it every time a new module comes out (not that there's going to be a lot that do this).

Comment: This is a shortcoming of the Gravatar module, not Drupal in general to be honest. It would be very easy to add an admin settings page that allowed you to choose how to output the image (with or without the link) but the developers have decided not to do that. Even in the latest dev build they haven't included this option so if I'm afraid if you want it you'll have to hack the module to make it better, or work around it as you're already doing

Comment: @Clive or instead of hacking the module... implement the feature and submit a patch to the module maintainers so others can use it too

Comment: @Chaulky Yep that'd be even better

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, handling directly in the Gravatar module would be best, but another option (though slightly hackish) would be to simply

```
$img = strip_tags(theme("user_picture", array('account' => $user_item)), "<img>");
```

Comment: this is great, but i can't understand what is the `$user_item` its giving me an error `Notice: Undefined variable: user_item in include() (line 24 of /localhost/drupal/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/comment--node-article.tpl.php).`

Comment: replace $user_item with $account or $user or whatever else you store user object in it